# How Can Unit Tests On iOS with Xamarin and F#

Tags: ios, testing, f#, xamarin

I am using Xamarin Studio 5.5 and I'd like to run my tests on the iOS simulator.
Sadly there is no template to create an iOS unit test project.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an empty F# project
2. Copy the following file (`AppDelegate.fs`) into your newly created project

   ```
   namespace ioslibrarytests //obviously you can choose any namespace you want

   open System
   open MonoTouch.UIKit
   open MonoTouch.Foundation
   open MonoTouch.NUnit.UI

   [<Register("AppDelegate")>]
   type AppDelegate() = 
       inherit UIApplicationDelegate()
       override val Window = null with get, set
       override this.FinishedLaunching(app, options) = 
           this.Window <- new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds)
           let runner = new TouchRunner(this.Window)
           runner.Add (System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly ());
           this.Window.RootViewController <- new UINavigationController (runner.GetViewController ());
           this.Window.MakeKeyAndVisible()
           true

   module Main = 
   [<EntryPoint>]
   let main args = 
       UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate")
       0
   ```
3. Create your test file. for example `Tests.fs` and follow this implementation pattern

   ```
   namespace ioslibrarytests

   open System
   open NUnit.Framework;

   [<TestFixture>]
   type Tests() =
        [<Test>]
        member me.Pass() = Assert.True (true)

        [<Test>]
        member me.Fail() = Assert.False (true)

        [<Test>]
        [<Ignore ("another time")>]
        member me.``Ignore me``() = Assert.True (false)
   ```

Please take care that

- your test class needs to have a default constructor => `type Tests() = ...`
- your test methods need to have an empty param list => `member me.Pass() = ...`